# How to get the result in the list with alternating sign using prolog?

Tags: list, prolog

The program is to generate an alternating result of the list.
For example ,{5,6,1} would be 5-6+1.

```
alternate(L,X) :-
   alternate(L,0,K,_).

alternate([],X,_,_).

alternate([H|T],A,p,S) :- !,
    AA is A + H,
    alternate(T,AA,m,S).

alternate([H|T],A,m,S) :- !,
    AA is A - H,
        alternate(T,AA,p,S).
```

The following is the tracing result:

```
alternate([5,6,1],S).
   Call: (10) alternate([5, 6, 1], _11626) ? creep
   Call: (11) alternate([5, 6, 1], 0, p, _12084) ? creep
   Call: (12) _12128 is 0+5 ? creep
   Exit: (12) 5 is 0+5 ? creep
   Call: (12) alternate([6, 1], 5, m, _12222) ? creep
   Call: (13) _12266 is 5-6 ? creep
   Exit: (13) -1 is 5-6 ? creep
   Call: (13) alternate([1], -1, p, _12360) ? creep
   Call: (14) _12404 is -1+1 ? creep
   Exit: (14) 0 is -1+1 ? creep
   Call: (14) alternate([], 0, m, _12498) ? creep//I expect it to return the X = 0 here.
   Exit: (14) alternate([], 0, m, _12542) ? creep
   Exit: (13) alternate([1], -1, p, _12586) ? creep
   Exit: (12) alternate([6, 1], 5, m, _12630) ? creep
   Exit: (11) alternate([5, 6, 1], 0, p, _12674) ? creep
   Exit: (10) alternate([5, 6, 1], _11626) ? creep
true.
```

I am using alternate([],X,*,*) to return X when there are no more elements, but I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you reach the end of the list you need to short-circuit the so-far-computed value in the  accumulator (second argument) into the "final result":

Instead of:

```
alternate([],X,_,_).
```

```
alternate([],X,_,X).
```

When starting off, start off with a `p`, and the accumlator at 0. On success, argument 4 will contain the final result:

```
alternate(L,X) :-
   alternate(L,0,p,X).
```

And so:

```
alternate(L,X) :-
   alternate(L,0,p,X).

alternate([],X,_,X).

alternate([H|T],A,p,S) :- !,
    AA is A + H,
    alternate(T,AA,m,S).

alternate([H|T],A,m,S) :- !,
    AA is A - H,
        alternate(T,AA,p,S).
```

```
?- alternate([1,2,3,4],X).
X = -2.
```

**Bonus: As a DCG**

This one is written in not-tail-recursive style so just needs to carry the "final sum" on each call, from which we compute a new "final sum" on predicate success:

```
alternate(List,Sum) :- phrase(alternate_p(Sum),List).

alternate_p(0)   --> [].
alternate_p(Sum) --> [X], alternate_n(TailSum), { Sum is TailSum+X }.

alternate_n(0)   --> [].
alternate_n(Sum) --> [X], alternate_p(TailSum), { Sum is TailSum-X }.
```

```
?- alternate([1,2,3,4],Sum).
Sum = -2 ;  % any additional solutions?
false.      % nope
```

**Bonus: Using foldl/4**

This being all about accumulating a value over a list in tail-recursive fashion, we can eschew writing the recursion ourselves, switch to "functional coding" and use `foldl/4`. We just need to write a predicate, here `alternator/3` which gets called for each list element, gets "stuff" from "the left" and builds "new stuff" and shifts it "to the right". In our case, "stuff" is a pair `[Sum,Multiplier]`:

```
% alternator(Element,FromLeft,ToRight)

alternator(Element,[Sum,Multiplier],[NewSum,NewMultiplier]) :-
   NewSum is Sum + Multiplier*Element,
   NewMultiplier is Multiplier*(-1).
   
% alternate(List,Sum) is an application of foldl/4:

alternate(List,Sum) :-
   foldl(alternator,List,[0,1],FoldlResult),
   FoldlResult = [Sum,_FinalMultiplier].
```

Again:

```
?-  alternate([1,2,3,4],Sum).
Sum = -2.
```